# Spring OAuth2 custom Authentication with external Redirects

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a custom authentication mechanism in Spring.
I have an authentication mechanism, that works like this:

- User visits any subpage of my page http://mypage
- User gets redirected to http://mypage/login, because my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is configured, that any Request (except to /login and /redirect, has to be authenticated)
- On the Login page a custom login mechanism happens, where I authenticate the user on an external site, that redirects the user's browser to the external page and then back to another subpage of my page: /redirect with custom data in the response
- On /redirect I set the `Authentication` of the user, depending on the custom data and add a `GrantedAuthority ROLE_FIRST`
- After this step the user is redirected to subpage /home, which is only visible to authenticated users with `GrantedAuthority ROLE_FIRST`.
- If the user clicks on a button on /home a `GrantedAuthority ROLE_SECOND` is added to the current `Authentication` of the user and the user is redirected to /secret
- The user is then authenticated with two factors (external login, buttonclick) and can see the content of /secret, which requires an authentication with `GrantedAuthority ROLE_SECOND`

So far so good, but I now want to redirect the user to the initial URL he tried to access. So if the user visited http://mypage/random in the first step, the user should be redirected to /random instead of /secret in the last step.
The problem is, I am loosing the URL in the step with the external login, because there is happening a external redirect and I can't pass the URL to the external service.

How can I manage this?

Bonus Question: What if the URL /random would be the URL to an OAuth2 Token interface instead? Would that change anything?